# Is there a way to remove html tags from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular5, primeng

I am working with the rich text editor component of `primeng`. This editor turns everything i type in into html. But sometimes i want to output these texts in plain text instead. Does angular 2 provide a way to easily remove the html tags from the text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can achieve this by `JavaScript`.

**Try this!!**

```
var plainText = content.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

This will return you plain text.

Comment: Great. I just replaced the coincidences by ` ` because my text is full of line breaks and <ul> tags

Comment: This will fail if there is a close angle bracket inside an attribute or a comment.

Comment: This answer really helped me with SharePoint rich text columns.  There is a lot of garbage markup in there, and it's hard to determine if empty.